# jQuery.url is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         $page = jQuery.url.attr("file");

         alert(page);


       });
```

but I get error jQuery.url is undefined and through firebug I was able to make sure that jquery.js is loaded

please advise

thanks

Comment: You **really** shouldn't prefix your non-jQuery-object variables with `$`. It is ugly and will confuse people (including you, in the line after you did not add the `$`). Besides that, use `var` to avoid creating globals.

Comment: Thanks alot ThiefMaster I appreciate your advices and will do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is no built-in `$.url` function.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.url) You're missing the jQuery URL plugin.